# adding extra parameter in a function stack value is getting corrupted

Tags: c

In c adding extra parameter in a function stack value is getting corrupted.
I am using vaargs in a function
so in following code if i remove one parameter it works fine but without removing msgptr value gets corrupted. 
please tell me solution for this

```
#define LOG_MSG(level, moduleId, msg,...)\ 
osLogMsg(level, moduleId,1,0,msg, ##__VA_ARGS__, 0xC0FFEE)

oslogmsg(int level,int id,boolean datatype,int temp,const char *msgPtr,...)
{
va_list argPtr;
va_start(argPtr, msgPtr);
intVal = va_arg(argPtr, WORD_t);
-----------
va_end(argPtr);
}
```

Comment: #define LOG_MSG(level, moduleId, msg,...)\ osLogMsg(0, 0, 0,1,msg, ##__VA_ARGS__, 0xC0FFEE)

Comment: i have tried all methods but its not getting the expected answer

Comment: Please show us a [mCVE].

Comment: @MichaelWalz what was happening is in oslogmsg it is not taking an extra argument if it does it results in stack corruption i mean msg value is getting corrupted.......if i send less than 4 arguments it is working fine so there is any solution to avoid the value getting corrupted

Comment: Your recent updates are still not enough.  You need to provide a complete piece of code that others can copy and run that reproduces the issue.  That's what a MCVE is.

Comment: @dbush the code is about 500 files so i am giving the small code which i am finding the issue

Comment: @KrishnamurthySetty that's why you should make a __minimal__ example that produces the problem. Of course that requires some work from you, but nothing is free in this world.

Comment: @MichaelWalz actually in my computer it is working fine but when i dump the code in to the arm board it is getting the issue i.e value gets corrupted so i thought it is due to memory issues that stack is getting less memory.........

Comment: @KrishnamurthySetty We can't know those issues unless we know how this function is called when the error happens and what the `-----------` part of the function is doing.

Comment: @KrishnamurthySetty then you should make a minimal example that fails on the arm board and show us that.

Comment: @dbush k i will try to make the code simple and revert u back as soon as possible that u can find out the issue more fastly.......thank u for all

Comment: @MichaelWalz can u tell me refer the link or some documents that i can understand the concepts of va argument in deeply and restriction of function arguments......

Comment: @KrishnamurthySetty google may be helpful here.

Comment: I observe that  only 64 bit value is corrupting means instead of value 1504 it is showing 1069446856704